# Hash password on API server or client?

Tags: api, rest, hash, passwords

Which is a better API design for sending passwords for user account creation?

**Hash raw password on Client then send to Server:**

```
// client code
$p = hash($p);
$api->save($p);
```

or

**Send raw password to Server then hash on Server:**

```
// api server code
$p = hash($_POST['p']);
$db->save($p);
```

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side you can find useful discussions in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, it's better to hash passwords on the server because you can control how you crypt passwords (algorithm, etc.) and you keep consistency.

I don't think you want to implement a password encryption logic in all clients you could have or let your users implement their own logic. Oh, and use SSL.

Comment: The API can provide standard hashing function to all clients.

Comment: Would it mean calling the API first to hash the password, and then calling the API again to send user data with encrypted password?

Comment: Kinda like that yeah. `$api->hash($p)` then `$api->send($p)`. The benefit of this is I think at least the password is hashed on transit.